# Android SimpleXml serialization with optional fields

Tags: android, xml-serialization

I'm trying to integrate a SimpleXml library in the project I'm working on. Is there a way to serialize models to XML with some fields being optional. Couldn't figure it out from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Object representation of the types you have defined:

double -> Double
int -> Integer

This allows you to define them as null like so:

```
@Root(name = "someWS")
public class GetSmth{
    @Element(name="Latitude", required=false)
    private Double latitude;

    @Element(name="Longtitude", required=false)
    private Double longtitude;

    @Element(name="PageNumber", required=false)
    private Integer pageNumber;

    @Element(name="PageSize", required=false)
    private Integer pageSize;

    @Element(name="CompanyDetailId")
    private Integer companyDetailId;


    public GetSmth(Double latitude, Double longtitude, Integer pageNumber,
                Integer pageSize, Integer companyDetailId) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longtitude = longtitude;
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
        this.companyDetailId = companyDetailId;
    }
}
```

Reviewing the [documentation](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#optional), required=false is more for the object de-serialization than for the object serialization.  So, you could use the primitive types there, but doing so would require that you use a non-null value during assignment.  Upon de-serialization, if your xml does not define latitude, latitude would be given a default init value of 0 instead of null.  Just depends upon what behavior you want.

**Edit:**

Be sure to define the constructor with the Object representations:

```
public GetSmth(Double latitude, Double longtitude, Integer pageNumber, 
    Integer pageSize, Integer companyDetailId)
```

Comment: If you update your question with the code producing the NPE I can give you a better answer then.

Comment: I saw that you updated, if your constructor requires the primitive types in the method declaration a NPE will be thrown if you supply null.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have an empty default constructor (or one which takes only the required fields), and then add setters for the optional properties. If you are concerned about mutability, use the `Builder` pattern to create the object with only the desired fields.

With the "partial" object (i.e, an object which has only some of its members set), Simple framework will serialize only the supplied fields into XML.

Comment: I second that technique.  Will it really not serialize primitive types if they are not specified?

Comment: Uh oh - I did not realize that we are specifically talking about primitive types here. I have not tried this, but I would think the primitives would still be serialized since they have default values.